# While deploying to AWS I'm getting Type error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/next-server/server/router' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

App is building fine in local but when deploying to AWS throwing this error:
Type error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/next-server/server/router' or its corresponding type declarations
What could be possible reason and how to fix it? Can anyone help please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzjN5.png)

Comment: Are you installing the `node modules` before starting your script? (`npm install`). `Cannot find module ...` is usually thrown when the module was not installed.

Comment: yes installing node module

Comment: What command are you using to build your project? Also are you able to build it locally?

Comment: yes i am able to build it locally without any error but when deploying to AWS amplify getting this error